# Convert array of hash in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Actually I have a Array of hash :

```rb
[{:id=>"6", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.159", :type=>"book"},
 {:id=>"8", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.097", :type=>"poem"},
 {:id=>"3", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.207", :type=>"book"}]
```

I would like something like :

```rb
{
 {:id=>"6", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.159", :type=>"book"},
 {:id=>"8", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.097", :type=>"poem"},
 {:id=>"3", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.207", :type=>"book"}
}
```

How can I do to convert it ?

Comment: What kind of object is that last code block?

Comment: ...That is, the last code block is not a valid Ruby object.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Though the second block of code you posted is not valid (because the hashes need to be tied to some other identifier or object), one could guess that you somehow want to regroup the objects of the array (which are hashes) into some other way.

If so, you could extract them to variables with something like this:

```rb
array_of_hashes = [{:id=>"6", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.159", :type=>"book"},
 {:id=>"8", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.097", :type=>"poem"},
 {:id=>"3", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.207", :type=>"book"}]

hash_1, hash_2, hash_3 = array_of_hashes
```

Another possibility is that you want to make those hashes be the values of another hash:

```rb
array_of_hashes = [{:id=>"6", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.159", :type=>"book"},
 {:id=>"8", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.097", :type=>"poem"},
 {:id=>"3", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.207", :type=>"book"}]

hash_of_hashes = array_of_hashes.each_with_object({}) do |hash, new_hash|
  id = hash[:id] # or some other calculated new key
  new_hash[id] = hash
end
```

This would produce a hash like this:

```rb
{ 
  "6" => {:id=>"6", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.159", :type=>"book"},
  "8" => {:id=>"8", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.097", :type=>"poem"},
  "3" => {:id=>"3", :created_at=>"2022-06-10", :value=>"2.207", :type=>"book"}
}
```